# To which philosophical direction, theory or philosopher does this panel from comic named "the allegory of the trolley problem paradox" refer to?

Tags: ethics, thought-experiment

I figured out the rest of panels, but stuck on this one. I think it's related to philosophy of language, but I can't pin down more specific answer for this one.

[image: Here's the panel]

As far as I understand it's about a man who can't understand Chinese at all and the only thing he can use is some type of manual. So I've concluded it's mocking some kind of language theory I'm not aware about.

I've searched through author's blog, but it's already dead (link: [link to the blog post in Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20071227180625/http://saintgasoline.com/2007/03/04/trolley-problems/)). It's only accessible through web archive. Also googled key words and the only thing I found is Wikipedia page about "philosophy of language". I couldn't find more specific things, so I was wondering, maybe somebody knows more about it?

Please, point me in the right direction.

Also I'll add the full comic just in case:

[image: Full comic]

If you're curious, I think other panels are about (I did some research):

1. Allegory of the cave;
2. Demon (thought experiment), more specifically Descartes’ malicious demon;
3. Zeno's paradoxes;
4. Veil of ignorance (moral reasoning device);
5. (?);
6. Ship of Theseus.

Comment: There is also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticking_time_bomb_scenario

Comment: @CriglCragl Thank you for interesting read!

Comment: It's a reference to the Chinese Room argument: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/chinese-room/

Comment: @DavidGudeman Why not an answer?

Comment: @DavidGudeman Thank you!

Comment: The fat man in panel 4 is also a reference to an extension of the trolley problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room

Probably this argument about how an AI would still not be conscious if it passed the Turing test as it would be like a person answering Chinese questions without actually understanding Chinese.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'll mark your answer as a solution a little bit later (right now I can't).